# Identify SQL statements from sys.dm_exec_sql_text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL script I wrote a few days ago to find CPU intense queries by using some DMV/DMFs and .sys tables (mostly from sys.dm_exec_query_stats).
However to determine the exact SQL statement that was executed at a point in time I am using the following (found in BOL and various blogs) in my SELECT statement: 
           `,SUBSTRING(t.text,s.statement_start_offset/2 +1,
                 (CASE WHEN s.statement_end_offset = -1 
                       THEN LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), t.text)) * 2 
                       ELSE s.statement_end_offset END - 
                       s.statement_start_offset)/2) AS 'TSQL-Query'`

Could someone explain why "s.statement_start_offset" is first divided by two and then added by one? And also why the LEN() statement is multiplied by two?

I see these examples in many blogs and also at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181929.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but I can't seem to find these details.

I also included my whole script below in order for you to get the bigger picture.

```
    SELECT TOP 20   
    COALESCE(DB_NAME(t.dbid),
                DB_NAME(CAST(a.value as int))) AS DBNAME                                
    ,SUBSTRING(t.text,s.statement_start_offset/2 +1,                                    
                 (CASE WHEN s.statement_end_offset = -1 
                       THEN LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), t.text)) * 2 
                       ELSE s.statement_end_offset END - 
                       s.statement_start_offset)/2)                                     
                        AS 'TSQL-Query' 
     ,s.execution_count AS 'Execution Count'
     ,s.total_worker_time AS 'Total CPU'
     ,s.total_worker_time/s.execution_count AS 'Avg CPU (ms)'     
     ,s.total_physical_reads AS 'Total Physical Reads'
     ,s.total_physical_reads/s.execution_count AS 'Avg Physical Reads'
     ,s.total_logical_reads AS 'Total Logical Reads'
     ,s.total_logical_reads/s.execution_count AS 'Avg Logical Reads'
     ,s.total_logical_writes AS 'Total Logical Writes'
     ,s.total_logical_writes/s.execution_count AS 'Avg Logical Writes'
     ,s.total_elapsed_time AS 'Total Duration (ms)'
     ,s.total_elapsed_time/s.execution_count AS 'Avg Duration/execution (ms)'
     ,p.query_plan AS 'ExecutionPlan'
     ,(SELECT sqlserver_start_time FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info) as 'Last Reboot'
     ,GETDATE() AS 'TimeStamp'
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s                                                       
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s.sql_handle) AS t                                     
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(s.plan_handle) AS p                                  
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(plan_handle) AS a                                   
 WHERE attribute = 'dbid' 
ORDER BY s.total_worker_time DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because data returned from `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` function is in Unicode. 1 character takes 2 bytes. The `SUBSTRING` works on character data types (not on bytes). So we need to divide the number of bytes by 2 + 1 to have location of the first character in SQL Query that is inside `text`.